# Best way to maintain reference to data needed throughout iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, reference

I have a number of view controllers embedded in navigation hierarchies and tab bar controllers. What is similar across all of the view controllers is that they all need to access the same data object. In my app delegate, I create the data object and create the initial view controllers needed for the `UITabBarController`.

Now I am left with a choice. I need all of my view controllers throughout the entire app able to reference that data object. The view controllers need to be able to both read and write to the data as well. So one option is to have a property for the data on every view controller and whenever a new view controller is created, the property is simply set to reference that data.

For example on every view controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ApplicationData *data; //This is the method I am using currently
```

So using this method, when I instantiate the first view controllers in the `AppDelegate`, I would set those view controllers (besides the tab bar controller and uinavigationcontrollers) ' `ApplicationData` properties to this data object created in my application delegate.

My second option is to make the `ApplicationData` object on the `AppDelegate` a property, allowing me to access the data through the delegate of the application singleton.

For example:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//then
data = appDelegate.data;
```

Looking around on StackOverflow, I have seen both of these methods used successfully and both have been successful for me.

**My question**: Is there a distinct advantage of one of these methods over the other? If not, what are some pros and cons and what is the recommended practice? Or is there a better method of passing around this data that I don't know?

Comment: Third option: Make the data object a singleton (more precisely: a shared instance), then all view controllers can access it via `[ApplicationData sharedData]`. - *I think* this is primarily opinion-based. I usually use the first method (passing objects from one VC to the next).

Comment: I'm a new, self taught programmer so I don't know a whole lot. I'll have to look into that but that sounds really interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider passing your data variables as you allocate a new instance of a view controller. There are some disadvantages putting the variables into app delegate.

1. Once you put the data into app delegate your data will be preserved application level in memory until your app is terminated.
2. Assume that your firstviewcontroller showing the data array, and secondviewcontroller removes the selected data. When you get back to firstviewcontroller there may be inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to work out inconsistencies for both methods though